# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte when reading an image

Tags: image, file, python-3.5, filepath

when l try to read an image as follow

```
with open('/home/image/482_PARTERRE_55682.jpg', 'r') as f:
    imagebin=f.read()
```

l get the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/home/vincent/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.5/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

l don't understand my error.

Answer (score 1):

You should open image in binary mode i.e. "rb"

```
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> fh = open(".sample.jpg", 'rb')
>>> img = Image.open(fh)
```

Answer (score -1):

with open('/home/image/482_PARTERRE_55682.jpg', 'rb') as f:
    imagebin=f.read()